# Set control id in vb.net repeater to property of datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a grid control in a VB.Net page and the item template is as follows

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <cc1:vprCheckBox runat="server" id="chkQLItem" Checked='<%# Eval("selected")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

On postback the id for this control is

```
<_ctl0_maincontent_grdql__ctl10_chkqlitem>on</_ctl0_maincontent_grdql__ctl10_chkqlitem>
```

Is there a way I could set it to include an ID, such as

```
<cc1:vprCheckBox runat="server" id="chkQLItem_<%#Eval('QLKey')%>" Checked='<%# Eval("selected")%>' />
```

So the output would be chkQLItem_123

Comment: Using GridView or Repeater ?

Comment: I am using a gridview

Comment: Did the answer not help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <cc1:vprCheckBox runat="server" id="chkQLItem_<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>"Checked='<%# Eval("selected")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can tweak it as well as per your requirements. Hope this helps!